# How to make two bxslider instances move at once? I tried changing delays, pauses and auto delays but no luck. :(

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Here's my code

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: true,
    controls: false,
    speed:500,
    pause: 2000,
    autoDelay:0
  });

  $('.names-slider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: true,
    controls: false,
    speed:500,
    pause: 2000,
    autoDelay:0
  });
```

Comment: Is your code in document ready?

Comment: @WisdmLabs Yes, I have kept it inside $(function(){}) which is in separate js file

Comment: Try to use IDs instead of class name while instantiating bxSlider, because if your document is large then it will take slight difference to start slider by class name. This is because, jQuery works faster for IDs than class names.

Comment: @WisdmLabs Changing it to ID's is not helping either.

Comment: I don't understand. Two sliders start with different time and after a while they start moving together just as I expected. Is this really because Jquery is searching for those elements and then once it is done,sliders sync perfectly? This seems a performance issue to me. Just as @WisdmLabs said, irrespective of assigning ID or CLASS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can initialize you `bxslider` with `auto:false`

```
var sliderone = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: false
});

var slidertwo = $('.names-slider').bxSlider({
    auto: false
});
```

and then using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to run the `goToNextSlide` function for both the sliders at the same time

```
var moveSlider = function(){
    sliderone.goToNextSlide();
    slidertwo.goToNextSlide();
}

setTimeout(moveSlider,2000);
```

Comment: Cerline Boss, you are a boss just like the name you have. I mean, what a piece of beauty is this logic. It never came to my fable mind :( Thanks alot. Just one minor thing. Instead of **setTimeout** I used **setInterval** to keep loop going. Thanks a lot. Also I don't have 15+ rep so can't vote you up but **+1** from me